# The official version of Cobalt

Tags: cobalt

We are going to run Cobalt on our device, and consider to the stability for partners' development.

We'd like to know...

1. The official version that Cobalt recommends.
2. Would Cobalt have a regular official version released? If the answer is yes, may I know the period of the release?

It would be great to know this information for partners preparing the environment for the future development.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The master branch at https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/ will always stay close to the internal development trunk. It will be a moving target in terms of stability, but will also see features first.

Release branches are sequentially named, COBALT_2, COBALT_3, and so on. They are named on when they branch, not when they stabilize, but in general it will be safest to port and release off of the latest stable release branch. These branches have gone through testing and released on one or more real production platforms.

Since this is still early days, there isn't a regular release schedule yet, but it is being worked towards. There will be more details on that when plans are finalized.